# Finding age on different planets

Tags: java, string, user-input

I'm writing a program that asks the user for their birthdate and then calculates their age in years of different planets. I am not suppose to assume how the birthdate is to be entered except that there is one white space between each number.

The code I have right now does not meet these specifications right now and I'm not sure how to write it otherwise. I am also having problem calculating what my age would be today. When I enter my birthdate and print out age, it currently tells me that I'm 407 yet when I print out dateBirth and today, both of those dates are correct.

```
System.out.print("Please enter your birthdate (mm dd yyyy): ");
birthdate = scan.nextLine();

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");
Date dateBirth = df.parse(birthdate);
Calendar calBirth = new GregorianCalendar();
calBirth.setTime(dateBirth);

Calendar calDay = new GregorianCalendar();
today = calDay.getTime();
age = (today.getTime() - dateBirth.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
```

Comment: The default for calDay is today's date

Comment: How can your birthday be different on a different planet? Probably, you mean age instead of birthday...
For a solution, try replacing <1000> with <1000L>. It's magic!

Comment: Yes, I too am confused. How is my birthday any different on another planet.

Comment: Why are you using `Calendar`?

Comment: You have another problem, in the requirements. There's no solution for arbitrary date formats in input. For example, if I enter "10 11 12", what date is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 is actually `31536000000` which is bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE this causes an overflow. As an integer it would be evaluated to `1471228928` which leads to the wrong result.

The solution is append the letter **L** to one of your constants

```
long div = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365L );
long age = ( today.getTime() - dateBirth.getTime() ) / div;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the expression `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365` evaluates to the result you are expecting and if not, find a way to get the expected result. Perhaps you should even consider that on earth, we have so called leap years and that you could tag your question as homework.

Comment: Don't forget the non-integral periods of the other planets. Finding out how the locals deal with it could be problematic, though.

Comment: Earth is also non-integral. A year is about 365.24 days

Answer (score 2):

```
1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
```

Is an int, but its to long to hold it. Make one of these a long, like:

```
1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
```